# How to plot a Histogram between 2 variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a Histogram that is Years vs Amount of female participants in the Olympics
but I dont know how to give 2 variables and plot them according to each other
I tried this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000


df = pd.read_csv("athlete_events.csv")
fig = plt.figure()
data = df[(df['Sex'] == 'M')].groupby('Year')['Sex'].count().reset_index()
data2 = df[(df['Sex'] == 'F')].groupby('Year')['Sex'].count().reset_index()
plt.hist(data['Year'], bins = 10)
plt.ylabel("Athlete per year",fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

and then I tried

```
plt.hist(data2['Year'],data2['Sex'], bins = 10)
```

But it didnt work

Comment: No I meant a normal histogram with bars and bins, but that has in the Y-axis the amount of female athletes and in the x-axis the years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already computed counts, you should use [**`bar()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) instead of [**`hist()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html). A standard way to to plot grouped counts is with [**`groupby()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)-[**`unstack()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```py
df.groupby('Year')['Sex'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(ylabel='Athlete per year')
```

[image: athletes per year by sex]

If you want to bin the year, [**`cut()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) the years and then [**`groupby()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the bins:

```py
df['Bin'] = pd.cut(df.Year, bins=10)
df.groupby('Bin')['Sex'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Athlete per year')
```

[image: athletes per binned year by sex]